# Image distorted when using it as Igraph node

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Consider the following example:

```
library(png)
library(igraph)

nodes=5
mat = matrix(runif(n = nodes*nodes,min = 0,max = 10),nodes,nodes)
mat.graph <- graph.adjacency(mat,weighted=TRUE,mode="undirected",diag=FALSE)
imgfilename <- file.path(tempdir(), "img.png")
imgfile <- download.file("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Circle-icons-water.svg/2000px-Circle-icons-water.svg.png",
                     destfile=imgfilename,mode='wb')
img <- readPNG(imgfilename)
V(mat.graph)$raster <- list(img,img,img,img,img)
plot(mat.graph ,vertex.size=E(mat.graph)$weight,edge.width=E(mat.graph)$weight,
 layout=layout.circle,vertex.shape="raster",vertex.label=NA,vertex.size=30, vertex.size2=30)
```

The issue I have is that the image that is being used as node gets distorted when plotted. Is it possible to keep the width/length ratio fixed?

Also, I see that the position of the nodes keeps changing every time as the values for the weights also change. Is it possible to keep the nodes also in a fixed position?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Btw, how to mix the raster image object with other node shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overriding the first `vertex.size` by including it twice. So one dimension is fixed while the other is dependent on the edge weights. Instead, set both vertex sizes based on edge weights:

```
plot(mat.graph,
     vertex.size=4*E(mat.graph)$weight,
     vertex.size2=4*E(mat.graph)$weight,
     edge.width=E(mat.graph)$weight,
     layout=layout.circle, 
     vertex.shape="raster", 
     vertex.label=NA)
```

However, note that the highest and lowest edge weights are in a ratio of about 16:1, so the smallest vertex is *much* smaller than the largest one.

[image]

Comment: Btw do you know why some edges do not reach the node?

Comment: Not sure. I'll update my answer if I come up with a fix.